# Batch normalization with 3D convolutions in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I'm implementing a model relying on 3D convolutions (for a task that is similar to action recognition) and I want to use batch normalization (see [[Ioffe & Szegedy 2015]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167)). I could not find any tutorial focusing on 3D convs, hence I'm making a short one here which I'd like to review with you.

The code below refers to TensorFlow r0.12 and it explicitly instances variables - I mean I'm not using tf.contrib.learn except for the tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm() function. I'm doing this both to better understand how things work under the hood and to have more implementation freedom (e.g., variable summaries).

I will get to the 3D convolution case smoothly by first writing the example for a fully-connected layer, then for a 2D convolution and finally for the 3D case. While going through the code, it would be great if you could check if everything is done correctly - the code runs, but I'm not 100% sure about the way I apply batch normalization. I end this post with a more detailed question.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# This flag is used to allow/prevent batch normalization params updates
# depending on whether the model is being trained or used for prediction.
training = tf.placeholder_with_default(True, shape=())
```

### Fully-connected (FC) case

```py
# Input.
INPUT_SIZE = 512
u = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, INPUT_SIZE))

# FC params: weights only, no bias as per [Ioffe & Szegedy 2015].
FC_OUTPUT_LAYER_SIZE = 1024
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
    [INPUT_SIZE, FC_OUTPUT_LAYER_SIZE], dtype=tf.float32, stddev=1e-1))

# Layer output with no activation function (yet).
fc = tf.matmul(u, w)

# Batch normalization.
fc_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(
    fc,
    center=True,
    scale=True,
    is_training=training,
    scope='fc-batch_norm')

# Activation function.
fc_bn_relu = tf.nn.relu(fc_bn)
print(fc_bn_relu)  # Tensor("Relu:0", shape=(?, 1024), dtype=float32)
```

### 2D convolutional (CNN) layer case

```py
# Input: 640x480 RGB images (whitened input, hence tf.float32).
INPUT_HEIGHT = 480
INPUT_WIDTH = 640
INPUT_CHANNELS = 3
u = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_CHANNELS))

# CNN params: wights only, no bias as per [Ioffe & Szegedy 2015].
CNN_FILTER_HEIGHT = 3  # Space dimension.
CNN_FILTER_WIDTH = 3  # Space dimension.
CNN_FILTERS = 128
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
    [CNN_FILTER_HEIGHT, CNN_FILTER_WIDTH, INPUT_CHANNELS, CNN_FILTERS],
    dtype=tf.float32, stddev=1e-1))

# Layer output with no activation function (yet).
CNN_LAYER_STRIDE_VERTICAL = 1
CNN_LAYER_STRIDE_HORIZONTAL = 1
CNN_LAYER_PADDING = 'SAME'
cnn = tf.nn.conv2d(
    input=u, filter=w,
    strides=[1, CNN_LAYER_STRIDE_VERTICAL, CNN_LAYER_STRIDE_HORIZONTAL, 1],
    padding=CNN_LAYER_PADDING)

# Batch normalization.
cnn_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(
    cnn,
    data_format='NHWC',  # Matching the "cnn" tensor which has shape (?, 480, 640, 128).
    center=True,
    scale=True,
    is_training=training,
    scope='cnn-batch_norm')

# Activation function.
cnn_bn_relu = tf.nn.relu(cnn_bn)
print(cnn_bn_relu)  # Tensor("Relu_1:0", shape=(?, 480, 640, 128), dtype=float32)
```

### 3D convolutional (CNN3D) layer case

```py
# Input: sequence of 9 160x120 RGB images (whitened input, hence tf.float32).
INPUT_SEQ_LENGTH = 9
INPUT_HEIGHT = 120
INPUT_WIDTH = 160
INPUT_CHANNELS = 3
u = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, INPUT_SEQ_LENGTH, INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_CHANNELS))

# CNN params: wights only, no bias as per [Ioffe & Szegedy 2015].
CNN3D_FILTER_LENGHT = 3  # Time dimension.
CNN3D_FILTER_HEIGHT = 3  # Space dimension.
CNN3D_FILTER_WIDTH = 3  # Space dimension.
CNN3D_FILTERS = 96
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
    [CNN3D_FILTER_LENGHT, CNN3D_FILTER_HEIGHT, CNN3D_FILTER_WIDTH, INPUT_CHANNELS, CNN3D_FILTERS],
    dtype=tf.float32, stddev=1e-1))

# Layer output with no activation function (yet).
CNN3D_LAYER_STRIDE_TEMPORAL = 1
CNN3D_LAYER_STRIDE_VERTICAL = 1
CNN3D_LAYER_STRIDE_HORIZONTAL = 1
CNN3D_LAYER_PADDING = 'SAME'
cnn3d = tf.nn.conv3d(
    input=u, filter=w,
    strides=[1, CNN3D_LAYER_STRIDE_TEMPORAL, CNN3D_LAYER_STRIDE_VERTICAL, CNN3D_LAYER_STRIDE_HORIZONTAL, 1],
    padding=CNN3D_LAYER_PADDING)

# Batch normalization.
cnn3d_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(
    cnn3d,
    data_format='NHWC',  # Matching the "cnn" tensor which has shape (?, 9, 120, 160, 96).
    center=True,
    scale=True,
    is_training=training,
    scope='cnn3d-batch_norm')

# Activation function.
cnn3d_bn_relu = tf.nn.relu(cnn3d_bn)
print(cnn3d_bn_relu)  # Tensor("Relu_2:0", shape=(?, 9, 120, 160, 96), dtype=float32)
```

What I would like to make sure is whether the code above exactly implements batch normalization as described in [[Ioffe & Szegedy 2015]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) at the end of Sec. 3.2:

> For convolutional layers, we additionally want the normalization to obey the convolutional property – so that different elements of the same feature map, at different locations, are normalized in the same way. To achieve this, we jointly normalize all the activations in a minibatch, over all locations. [...] Alg. 2 is modified similarly, so that during inference the BN transform applies the same linear transformation to each activation in a given feature map.

**UPDATE**
I guess the code above is also correct for the 3D conv case. In fact, when I define my model if I print all the trainable variables, I also see the expected numbers of beta and gamma variables. For instance:

```py
Tensor("conv3a/conv3d_weights/read:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 128, 256), dtype=float32)
Tensor("BatchNorm_2/beta/read:0", shape=(256,), dtype=float32)
Tensor("BatchNorm_2/gamma/read:0", shape=(256,), dtype=float32)
```

This looks ok to me since due to BN, one pair of beta and gamma are learned for each feature map (256 in total).

---

[Ioffe & Szegedy 2015]: Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift

Answer (score 2):

That is a great post about 3D batchnorm, it's often unnoticed that batchnorm can be applied to any tensor of rank greater than 1. Your code is correct, but I couldn't help but add a few important notes on this:

- A "standard" 2D batchnorm (accepts a 4D tensor) can be significantly faster in tensorflow than 3D or higher, because it supports `fused_batch_norm` implementation, which applies [one kernel operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#common_fused_ops):

  > Fused batch norm combines the multiple operations needed to do batch
  >   normalization into a single kernel. Batch norm is an expensive process
  >   that for some models makes up a large percentage of the operation
  >   time. Using fused batch norm can result in a 12%-30% speedup.

  There is [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5694) to support 3D filters as well, but there hasn't been any recent activity and at this point the issue is closed unresolved.
- Although the original paper prescribes using batchnorm before ReLU activation (and that's what you did in the code above), there is evidence that it's probably better to use batchnorm *after* the activation. Here's a comment on [Keras GitHub](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1802#issuecomment-187966878) by Francois Chollet:

  > ... I can guarantee that recent code written by Christian [Szegedy] 
  >   applies relu
  >   before BN. It is still occasionally a topic of debate, though.
- For anyone interested to apply the idea of normalization in practice, there's been recent research developments of this idea, namely [weight normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07868) and [layer normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450), which fix certain disadvantages of original batchnorm, for example they work better for LSTM and recurrent networks.